# Symfony command runned by cron, but no effect. Runs fine on command line

Tags: php, symfony, cron

I'm currently making a mail client with Symfony 2.7. I've made a command to collect new mails with IMAP and create entities from them.
This command runs fine in command line, it collects and displays new mails.

Here is the command :

```
protected function configure()
{
    parent::configure();
    $this
        ->setName('app:mails:collect')
        ->setDescription('Collects new mails from every Mailboxes.');
}

protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();

    $mailboxes = $em->getRepository('MIPMailBundle:MailBox')->findAllActive();

    foreach ($mailboxes as $mailbox){
        $imapBox = new ImapMailbox('{'.$mailbox->getServer().':143/notls/norsh/novalidate-cert}INBOX',
                                    $mailbox->getAdress(), $mailbox->getPassword(), "web/mails/", "UTF-8");

        if (count($mailbox->getMails()) == 0){
            $output->writeln("Getting mails from mailbox...");
            $mailsIds = $imapBox->searchMailbox('ALL');
            if(!$mailsIds) {
                $output->writeln($mailbox->getAdress() . " is empty");
            }
        } else {
            $output->writeln("Searching for new mails...");
            $mailsIds = $imapBox->searchMailbox('UNSEEN');
            if(!$mailsIds) {
                $output->writeln("No new mail for " . $mailbox);
            }
        }

        foreach ($mailsIds as $mailId){

            //Creates new mail entities...

            $imapBox->markMailAsRead($mailId);
        }
    }

    $em->flush();
}
```

I want this command to be runned every minute by the server. So I've made a cronjob for this :

```
* * * * * /path/to/myapp/app/console app:mails:collect
```

But the command doesn't work if runned by cron. I tried to write the output to a file, but the file is empty. In cron logs, I can see the job executed :

```
Jul 19 09:39:01 dev CRON[26967]: (web) CMD (/path/to/myapp/app/console app:mails:collect)
```

but it doesn't work... I tried to specify environment (i work in dev env) by specifying it in the command :

```
* * * * * /path/to/myapp/app/console app:mails:collect --env=dev
```

This was unsuccesful. Any idea why ? Thanks

Comment: Is the path to console, relative or absolute?

Comment: tell me the exact command in your cron file

Comment: The exact command in my crontab is :

`* * * * * /var/www/MIP/app/console mip:mails:collect --env=dev`

so it's absolute path, yes

Comment: you have to run this using php

Comment: * * * * * php /var/www/MIP/app/console mip:mails:collect --env=dev

Comment: or    * * * * * /path/to/php /var/www/MIP/app/console mip:mails:collect --env=dev

Comment: I tried both, with a restart of cron service after, but it's not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works fine for me. `cd` into directory first then run. Do this see what happens.

```
* * * * * cd /path/to/myapp && php app/console app:mails:collect --env=dev
```

Use either `bin/console` or `app/console`! Depending on your setup.

**Note:** When you run out of options, try to use a very simple command (something like printing "hello world" to terminal) to see if it is your command or something else.

Comment: I tried with this (full command) : `* * * * * cd /var/www/MIP && php app/console mip:mails:collect --env=dev>>/var/www/MIP/log.log`  and this runs fine !! Why do I have to cd in my app directory first ? Isn't that a bit weird ? oO
Thanks a lot BentCoder !

Comment: It normally should work without `cd` but sometimes when things don't work, we have to do things differently. It is manual process this time.

Answer (score 1):

try to specify php executable path:

```
* * * * * /path/to/php /path/to/myapp/app/console app:mails:collect --env=dev
```

ex:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/myapp/app/console app:mails:collect --env=dev
```

Comment: I tried with php path, no further effect.

`Jul 19 10:33:01 mip-dev CRON[29046]: (web) CMD (/usr/bin/php /var/www/MIP/app/console mip:mails:collect --env=dev)`

That's what the log says, but no new entity :(

Comment: try to log command output, and check tmp.log for errors: * * * * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/myapp/app/console app:mails:collect >> /var/log/tmp.log

Comment: If you change "web/mails/" with absolute path anything changes?

Comment: "web/mails" ? I don't understand. I use absolute paths in the command, this is it : `* * * * * php /var/www/MIP/app/console mip:mails:collect --env=dev>>/var/www/MIP/log.log`

Comment: here: $imapBox = new ImapMailbox('{'.$mailbox->getServer().':143/notls/norsh/novalidate-cert}INBOX',
                                    $mailbox->getAdress(), $mailbox->getPassword(), "web/mails/", "UTF-8");